# Function objectContains

Tags: javascript

I need to create a function that looks inside a nested object for a specific {key:value}.

The object, key, and value will be given as a parameter.
If both the key and value are in the object together I have to return true, otherwise false

```
function objContains = function(obj, prop, value){
    for (let key in obj) {
      if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
        objContains(obj[key], prop, value)
      }
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && obj[key] === value) {
        return true
      }
    }
    return false
  }
```

I tried this but I can´t make it work

Comment: You probably want to `return objContains(obj[key], prop, value);`. You're calling it recursively but the return value is unused

Comment: Also note it will be faster if you check the current object for the property before recursing. If it is at the top of your object you won't need to recurse all the way down.

Comment: See the lnked question's answers. Basically, with any recursive function, when you do the recursion (when the function calls itself), you need to do something with the result of that call. In your case, since your function should return `true` when the property is found, you need to check if the recursive call returned `true` and, if so, return `true` (but **don't** return `false` if the recursive call returned `false`, since you need to keep looking).